# Select a value in Listbox and set focus over that value - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select a value in Listbox dynamically. But am not able to do so. I am getting an error, Object doesn't support this property or method.

Here is the code,

```
ReqSearchvalue = Range("B" & reqrow).Value

Sheets("Main").Activate

With Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox
    .Values = ReqSearchvalue
    .SetFocus = ReqSearchvalue
End With
```

Kindly share your thoughts. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is it an ActiveX or a UserForm ListBox?

Comment: ActiveX ListBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to @Peh for correcting this.

Loop through the `List` to find the index of the value you're looking and then set the `.Selected(idx)` to True.

```
Dim i As Long, found As Boolean
With Worksheets("Main").OLEObjects("Ent_ListBox").Object
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .List(i) = ReqSearchvalue Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If found then .Selected(i) = True
End With
```

Comment: It gives me an error on this line - 'If .List(i).Value = ReqSearchvalue Then'

Comment: @Sid29 it should be `.List(i)` instead of `.List(i).Value` and `.Selected(idx) = True` instead of `.SelectedItem(idx) = True`. `YourListBoxControl` should be `Worksheets("Main").OLEObjects("Ent_ListBox").Object` in your case.

Comment: @Peh ya that worked. Thanks Sir :) Can you make those changes in the answer, I will mark it - at Kostas K.

Comment: Just for completeness: This will always select the first entry (index = 0) if the `ReqSearchvalue` is not found in the listbox, and it throws an error if the listbox is empty. You can avoid this by replacing `idx As Long` with `found As Boolean` and replace `idx = i` with `found = True` and use `If found = True Then .Selected(i) = True` instead of `.Selected(idx) = True`. This way the selection isn't changed when nothing found and no error if the box is empty.

Comment: @Peh Thanks bro, much cleaner this way.

Answer (score -1):

`ListBox.SetFocus` is a method, it sets the focus on listbox itself, you cannot assign value to it. You must find desired item's index and use `.SelectedItem(index)` then.